# Activity recreate issue in Android Nougat Only?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have developed small project, in which there are three fragments added in a single activity.
I am getting an issue in Nougat only i.e. 
Start the application and go from fragment 1 -> fragment 2 and in fragment 2 there is a single button on this button click open external browser and when press back button, activity reload again and start from fragment 1.

In below versions from Nougat it is working perfectly, it back on fragment 2 but in Nougat (Samsung Galaxy s8+) it activity reloads and starts from fragment 1.

so please help me to resolve this issue.
thanks

Comment: One possible scenario that I'm thinking would be: `Don't keep activities activated` + Incorrect handling of fragments. Can you check in the Developer tools to see if `Don't keep activities` is on?

Comment: i can share my code. i am adding fragments in activity like this





public void addHomeFragment() {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.mFrame_container, homeFragment.newInstance(), HomeFragment.TAG)
                .addToBackStack(HomeFragment.TAG)
                .commit();
    }

Comment: Can you also check for that option to see if it's enabled? You  can find it at: Settings -> Developer Options -> Don't keep activities

Comment: getting same issue if i redirect from Activity 1 -> Activity 2 and from Activity 2 open external browser on click button and press back button than Activity 1 reload.

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: thanks @lulian 
its working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your code in `onResume` where if you are reloading the `ViewPager` or setting the `currentItem`.

Other Reason can be `Don't keep activities activated`. Can you check in the Developer tools to see if Don't keep activities is on? 
You can check it from `Device settings` Like this:

**Settings -> Developer Options -> Don't keep activities**